# Is there a “new” canonical test for fonts and languages?

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdftex, luatex

The example below was an accepted means for dealing with fonts, loading polyglossia versus babel, etc., before the 2016 changes to fontspec:

```
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifxetex%                               uses fontspec
  \usepackage{fontspec}%                check package docs
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
  \usepackage{xunicode}%                check if outmoded
  \usepackage{xltxtra}%                 check if outmoded
\else
  \ifluatex%                            also uses fontspec
    \usepackage{fontspec}%              check package docs
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
  \else%                                traditional NFSS
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
  \fi
\fi
```

So should one attempt to test for pre-2016 versions anymore? Should one just drop xunicode and xltxtra (given the fontspec doc reference to euenc)? Should {Ligatures=TeX} replace {Mapping=tex-text} since they are functionally equivalent?

My goal is to provide a generic framework for making a (relatively) engine-agnostic document. I may fold in language support into this example. I have other structures that test for xetex, pdftex, luatex in pdf or dvi mode, and regular tex dvi mode.

Comment: As an addendum, the minimal test for loading TikZ appears to be:
`\usepackage{ifxetex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{tikz}\else
  \ifpdf\usepackage{tikz}\fi
\fi`

Comment: what??? why not simply `\usepackage{tikz}` why wrap it in tests? (it works with at least latex, pdflatex, xetex, luatex. what other engines are you testing for?)

Comment: I had the Windows-based dvi reader that comes with TeX Live totally crash when using tikz and dvi. In Ubuntu everything functions, albeit with unexpected results with my diagrams.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you haven't (for a long time, not just last year) needed to load xunicode, xltxtra,

or specify the tex mapping (which is the default since 2014) so all you need is

```
\ifx\Umathchardef\undefined
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\else
     \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
```

Comment: Okay this is handy and upon testing, it works a treat. I have used the e-tex '\ifdefined\Umathchar  ... \fi' before, but since some templates in certain popular TeX editors still load these other packages, I was confused as to the general state of affairs. This approach also works to choose babel or polyglossia.

Comment: This way also ensures better handling of traditional TeX ligatures, e.g., `\'a`, than the example in my question. Using that example will cause traditional ligatures not to work properly in some macros using, e.g., `\uppercase`. This solution fixes that issue.

Comment: @CharlesP.Schaum sorry I  can't guess what you mean by that comment. `\uppercase` shouldn't be used in latex documents anyway (certainly not for uppercasing natural language text) `\MakeTextUppercase` is the latex command and works with `\'{a}` etc (which doesn't use the tex ligature mechanism)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was capping the first letter of an argument within a macro via \uppercase. When using what I posted, where the first letter was a tex ligature, it worked under latex and pdflatex, but not xelatex and lualatex. With your solution it works under all cases. But I will move to a latex-based solution.